# ES6 change object vaues shorthand

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, shorthand

It seems to me that once saw shorter solution than this:

```
let obj = { id: 12345, name: "Some name", desc: "Description" }

someFunction(id, name, desc) {
  obj.id = id;
  obj.name= name;
  obj.desc= desc;
}
```

Can somebody tell me if there is a faster way to assign new values with the same name?

Comment: Something like `Object.assign`?

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the current properties of `obj`, or create a new version of `obj` with the new properties?

Comment: NB: It would be better to pass *obj* as argument to your function.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
let obj = {id: 12345, name: 'Some name', desc: 'Description'}
Object.assign(obj, {id: 54321})
console.log(obj) // {id: 54321, name: 'Some name', desc: 'Description'}
Object.assign(obj, {id: 123, name: 'Some other name', desc: 'New description'})
console.log(obj) // {id: 123, name: 'Some other name', desc: 'New description'}
```

Comment: This is a bad way of doing `Object.assign`. The target should be an empty object. Your code will alter the soure object
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: @PraneshRavi, it seems from the question that mutation is indeed the *purpose* of the OP.

Comment: @PraneshRavi I disagree. What would be the purpose of specifying the target object if it should always be an empty object? And I think that the OP wants to alter the object.

Comment: This `obj = {id, name, desc}` will solve. Why use `Object.assign`?

Comment: @PraneshRavi That reassigns `obj`, so it effectively removes other properties, and it's not possible if object was declared using `const`.

Comment: Go through the examples in the above link. Just show me a place where the first parameter for `Object.assign()` is a non-empty object.

Comment: @PraneshRavi [This one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Merging_objects)?

Comment: Merging is different from assigning. Even that's not valid if two objects shares at least one property in common.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Merging_objects_with_same_properties

Comment: @PraneshRavi Not sure what your point is. Merging is a perfectly valid use of `Object.assign` if merging is what you want to do. In this case, it might be what the OP wants.

Comment: @Gothdo Sometimes it is not enough to just answer the question but to point out bad style. And mutating an reference type is bad style. Instead of `Object.assign(obj, {id: 54321})` `Object.assign({}, obj, {id: 54321})` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to property shorthand?

```
let id = '12345';
let name = 'Some name';
let desc = 'Description';

let obj = { id, name, desc };
```

Comment: Can you show how to rewrite the OP's `someFunction` code using this?

Comment: @torazoburo, why would that function need to be rewritten, when this replaces that function, making the latter unnecessary.

Comment: @trincot How so? Neither can we assume that the function is real code (in reality it might do a lot more), nor that the object should be replaced.

Comment: @zeroflagL, we should indeed not assume that the object should be replaced (which is the weak point of this answer, cf. my comment on Gothdo's answer), but that does not mean `someFunction` needs to be *rewritten* for the purpose of assigning the property values. IMO that is a very restrictive interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
function someFunction(id, name, desc) {
  Object.assign(obj, {id, name, desc});
}
```